# can this function get any faster in performance?

Tags: javascript, optimization, prototype

the function already tells you what it does, but anyway, it wraps angle and makes sure it's between 0-360. it's Javascript:

```
Number.prototype.wrapAngle = function(){
    var d = this;
    while(d > 360){ d -= 360;};
    while(d < 0){ d += 360;};
    return d.toString();
}
```

I need 'wrapAngle' to be fastest possible!

Comment: use Math.max/min: no need for a slow loop...

Comment: Use the `%` operator to compute a modulus.

Comment: @dandavis, max/min is incorrect behavior for the desired function. Modulus division (as answered by both Barmar and Alex Wayne) produces the correct behavior. (Well, modulus isn't perfect if the function needs to always return a positive value, but you could simply test whether the final result was negative and add 360 to the result in that case.)

Comment: yup, a conditional could gate the range just like min/max/abs could, and without all the call parens. i like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use modulo?

```
-721 % 360; // -1
390  % 360; // 30
90   % 360; // 90
```

So:

```
Number.prototype.wrapAngle = function(){
    var d = this % 360;
    if (d < 0) { // ensure positive number.
      d += 360;
    }

    // return a number, not a string.
    // This is a math based transformation of a number, so it should be a number.
    return d; 
}
```

Since modulus can return a negative number, but that number is *always* closer to zero than `-360` you can simply increment it *once* if it's negative.

Performance comparison: http://jsperf.com/wrapangle

Comment: OP wants a number >0.

Comment: need string because it's going to sit between a css like: transform: blabla X;

Comment: @Mack the number prototype should have methods that return numbers, generally. That would also allow you to easily use this method for math, and not _just_ for display. Convert it to a string when you create the style rule, and not a moment sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulus operator.

```
Number.prototype.wrapAngle = function(){
    return (this % 360).toString();
}
```